# How to specify IP address for outgoing connection?

Tags: crystal-lang

My server has two IP addresses. If I have two Crystal apps for example, how can I make each of them to work with specified IP address?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the bind address of [TCP](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/TCPServer.html#new%28host%3AString%2Cport%3AInt%2Cbacklog%3DSOMAXCONN%2Cdns_timeout%3Dnil%2Creuse_port%3Dfalse%29-class-method)/[HTTP](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/HTTP/Server.html) servers in their constructor, however its currently impossible to specify the bind address of an outbound TCP or HTTP connection in crystal.

Comment: I read the question as how to specify it for a client, not a server.

Comment: @JonneHaß Yep, I misunderstood the question. I just edited this to fix it.